# Is there a reason to use 4 diodes instead of 2 when controlling a motor with L293B?

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller

I am looking at the [datasheet of L293B](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjT09K4gfnmAhVvk4sKHTuXCKwQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fdatasheet%2Fcd00000058.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0dDVcijidXdjXs75J2WBxJ) and there are some usage examples provided in it:

[image]

**Is there a reason to use 4 diodes instead of just 2?**

[image]

Why are these connections needed here in the first place? What would be wrong with just connecting Output 1 and Output 2 alone to the motor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What would be wrong with just connecting Output 1 and Output 2 alone
>   to the motor?

In your 2 diode diagram you have the motor completely shorted out: -

[image]

4 diodes are needed when you have a full bridge driver to ensure motor back emfs  adequately push excess motor energy (due to inductance) back to the supply rails. You also need a reasonably good reservoir capacitor on those supply rails too.

Comment: Oh my... What was I thinking?.. Silly me. :D Thanks.